# Как объединить данные JS скрипты?

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть два скрипта для форма. Первый ajax скрипт отправляет ajax форму с данными на е-майл. Второй скрипт отправляет данные из формы на сервис E-sputnik. Я могу их подключить по одному. Возможно сделать что бы форма и отправляла на е-майл и на е-спутник? Вот скрипты

Скрипт отправки данные в e-sputnik

```
$(document).on("submit", ".popup-form", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var btn_submit = $(this).find('[type=submit]');

    var data = {
        'action': 'userSubscribe',
        'form_data': form_data,
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $.magnificPopup.close();
                        window.open(thxDomain,"_self")
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
            console.log('Dispatch error. Have fun :)');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Скрипт отправки данные на е-майл

```
$(".popup-form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pathPhp, //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
      $.magnificPopup.close();
      window.open(thxDomain,"_self")
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы можете объединить их в один:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".popup-form", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var btn_submit = $(this).find('[type=submit]');

    var data = {
        'action': 'userSubscribe',
        'form_data': form_data,
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $.magnificPopup.close();
                        window.open(thxDomain,"_self")
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
            console.log('Dispatch error. Have fun :)');
        }
    });
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: pathPhp, //Change
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
    $.magnificPopup.close();
    window.open(thxDomain,"_self")
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Done Functions
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

На мой взгляд лучшим решением будет создать две функции и уже их вызывать в обработчике.